# How do I access a service on a kubernetes node from another node on the same cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-service

My service description:

```
kubernetes describe service app-checklot --namespace=app-test-gl

Name:              app-checklot
Namespace:         app-test-gl
Labels:            app=app-checklot
                   chart=app-checklot-0.1.0
                   heritage=Tiller
                   release=chkl
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=app-checklot,release=chkl
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.99.252.76
Port:              https  11080/TCP
TargetPort:        11080/TCP
Endpoints:         85.101.213.102:11080,85.101.213.103:11080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I am able to access the pods separately using the individual ip's:

```
http://85.101.213.102:11080/service
http://85.101.213.103:11080/service
```

Also the service using the IP (this needs to be configured from another node by means of the url):

```
http://10.99.252.76:11080/service
```

What I would want is to access the service (app-checklot) using the service name in the url - so that I needn't update the url always . Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns):

> For example, if you have a `Service` called "**my-service**" in a Kubernetes
>   `Namespace` called "**my-ns**", a DNS record for "**my-service.my-ns**" is
>   created. `Pods` which exist in the "**my-ns**" Namespace should be able to
>   find it by simply doing a name lookup for "**my-service**". `Pods` which
>   exist in other `Namespaces` must qualify the name as "**my-service.my-ns**".
>   The result of these name lookups is the cluster IP.

Another service, deployed to the **same namespace**, would be able to call `http://app-checklot/service`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from within the cluster your service should be available at:

```
http://app-checklot.app-test-gl:11080/service
```